# How to retrieve Azure Copy Task name?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Pipeline but want to retrieve the name of the copy task and pass this to a stored procedure - how do I do this?

I can retrieve the Pipeline Name but can you also retrieve the Copy Task name without typing it in?  There does not appear to be a system variable unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you mean a **data factory** pipeline? Azure Pipelines (and the tag you used) is a completely different product.

Comment: so in the above is their a way to lookup the name 'JobHeader' from a system variable?

Comment: I don't know. Please refer to my previous question -- I'm familiar with Azure Pipelines, **not** Data Factory. I believe this question is mistagged, and I am asking you to clarify by reviewing and revising the tags.

Comment: Just for clarification the above is an Azure Pipeline created within Azure Data Factory

Comment: So it's *not* an Azure Pipeline. It's a **Data Factory** pipeline. "Azure Pipelines" is a specific product that is distinct from Data Factory. Please use the appropriate tags in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you have to manually provide the task names and there are no out of the box feature as of now in ADF to dynamically provide it